# result of memcpy(&x[0], "fsd", 3)

Tags: c++

```
        string x;
 78     x.reserve(100);
 79     x[0] = '1';
 80     x[1] = '2';
 81     x[2] = '\0';
 82     x.resize(3);
 83     cout << "sdfs: " << x.c_str() << endl;
 84     cout << &x[0] << endl;
 85     return 0
```

test result: print nothing

Comment: The title and the text of your post are not in sync.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` does not necessarily store its data as C strings, i.e. with a `\0` appended. Instead, the length of the string is held internally. If you change the contents, that's fine, but `resize()` does not know that there is actual data, as the length is still 0 from `string`'s point of view. Quoting from the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/):

> If n is greater than the current length of the string, the content is expanded by appending as many instances of the c character as needed to reach a size of n characters.

The `c` character in this call is \0, so `resize()` actually changes your string back to the empty one.

This is the correct behavior, as directly modifying the contents of `std::string` in this way is not supported. Use `operator[]`, `append` and so on instead.

Comment: This answer is more confusing than the question(if any).

Answer (score 2):

```
 78     x.reserve(100);
```

This just reserves memory for the string. It means that now you can append 100 characters to the string without the string having to reallocate memory.

*This does not change the size of the string.* `x` *is still an empty string.*

```
 79     x[0] = '1';
 80     x[1] = '2';
 81     x[2] = '\0';
```

This is accessing indexes out of bounds (which you can get away with if the implementation does not provide runtime checks, since you have reserved the memory)

```
82     x.resize(3);
```

This produces a valid string, 3 characters in length, each character with the default value (`'\0'`).

Answer (score 1):

You should take your time to make sure that you do actually ask a question, and also keep the title and the question in sync. As to what might be puzzling you (your code is what puzzles me), `std::string::resize()` will fill with '\0' the new elements created, overwriting your previous edit. Move the `resize()` over the assignment and you will be fine.